# Ideas for how to color polyline segments based on the number of segments in proximity to said polyline segment

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

This title is really a mouthful, sorry about that. I'm looking to create a kind of polyline heatmap, where lines are displayed in a different color depending on how many lines there are within proximity distance to it.
Something like this.

[image]

Is there any creative way for me to do this in leaflet? I appreciate any and all ideas.